# Можно ли подключиться к webapp напрямую?

Tags: telegram, web-apps

Можно ли подключиться к webapp Telegram напрямую через ссылку в браузере и т.п., telegram передаёт какие-то доп.параметры в ссылку как их получить?

Comment: Нажмите F12 (инструменты разработчика), вкладка `Network` и посмотрите запросы.